# Add web part zone to page based on search result layout

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, search-results, web-part-zone

I could use some advice on how to add a web part zone to a page in Sharepoint 2013 on premise. I have not done any front-end customizations like this before.
I have created a page based on the "Search results" layout. This layout has a left navigation zone where you can add web parts (for instance refinement panel) and a main zone where you can add web parts (usually search results).
I would like to add a web part zone to the right, where there seem to be plenty of free space. How can I add that?

When I open the page in Sharepoint Designer and select "Edit page layout", I am only allowed to edit it in "advanced mode" and it seems like I am redirected to the master page "SearchResults.aspx". Also, it is not possible to insert "Web Part Zone" anywhere in the page...

Comment: I'm new to SharePoint and is there a step by step instructions on how to do that.
any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on SharePoint Publishing. The Enterprise Search Center Site uses SharePoint Publishing for page creation. That means that a new page is based on a Page Layout which is bound to a Content Type. If you want a new Layout (which you do) you should copy the layout that most closely matches your needs (the Search Results page layout) and rename and retitle it so you can tell it's yours. Add your web part zone and save it back to the Master Page Gallery.

Now you can test your Page Layout by creating a new page based on your page layout in the browser. Then add what ever web parts you like to the new zone.